# connecting to vncserver if started with service

Tags: vnc, vncviewer

I've followed the instructions here to set up a vncserver service:  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04

I only used the section on setting up the vncserver service since I already had vnc4server installed.

Options for starting vncserver:

1. Use the service I created by running:
   `sudo service vncserver start/stop/restart`.  It works fine and kicks of the Xvnc4 process.
2. Simply type vncserver into the terminal.

In both cases, I have double checked that the Xvnc4 service associated with vnc4server is started and running using `ps -aux | grep vnc`.

In both cases, a display is created and attached to display 1.

My problem:
When I use option 1 to start my vncserver, I am unable to connect to the display created from my windows pc using vncviewer.

When I use option 2, I am able to connect to the display from my windows pc using vncviewer.  I simply provide `serverip:<display#>`.

Why can't I connect when I use option 1.  Also, is the suggestion to setup a secure tunnel using something like putty and then connecting through it just for security?  I ask because when I start my vncserver using option 2 above, I'm able to connect remotely using `servername or ip:display#` without using putty or any kind of tunnel.

Here is my `~/.vnc/xstartup`:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
startxfce4 &
```

Here is my `/etc/init.d/vncserver` service file:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/"
export USER="mo"
DISPLAY="1"
DEPTH="16"
#GEOMETRY="1024x768"
#GEOMETRY="1600x1200"
GEOMETRY="1366x768"
OPTIONS="-depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY} -localhost"
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
start)
log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"
;;

stop)
log_action_begin_msg "Stopping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"
;;

restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
esac
exit 0
```

Comment: Since the `/etc/init.d/vncserver` file includes option `-localhost`, you **will** need to tunnel the connection as indicated i.e. `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l user server_ip_address`. See for example [vncserver -localhost and ssh tunneling](https://superuser.com/questions/715604/vncserver-localhost-and-ssh-tunneling)

Comment: So where do I input the command `ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -N -f -l user server_ip_address`? In putty settings?  Or on a ssh session I connect to through putty?

Comment: Ok. I got it to work.  Thanks for the pointer.  I had my putty tunnel setup wrong.  I was using the remote server address instead of localhost.  But I still want to know how I can connect to more than one vnc display so I can work across two monitors?  I'm guessing I have to set up a second tunnel?

Comment: I think I figured it out.  I should be able to set up more than one tunnel on my putty connection and connect using different ports.  I just need to figure out how the use my vncserver service to start another display on my server.

Comment: Problem solved.  I was able to edit my vncservice to start multiple displays.

Comment: Great - perhaps you could find time to write up an answer, to help others?

Comment: Absolutely.  Doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to steeldriver's pointers, my problem was that my settings in putty on my pc were wrong.  I was using my remote server address rather than using "localhost".  To address my need for two displays, I set up two different tunnels in putty under the same connection:

```
localhost:5901

localhost:5902
```

I then modified my /etc/init.d/vncserver to start two instances of vncserver on two different displays.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin/"
export USER="mo"
DISPLAY="1"
DISPLAY2="2"
DEPTH="16"
#GEOMETRY="1024x768"
#GEOMETRY="1600x1200"
GEOMETRY="1366x768"
OPTIONS="-depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY} -localhost"
OPTIONS2="-depth ${DEPTH} -geometry ${GEOMETRY} :${DISPLAY2} -localhost"

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
start)
log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS}"


log_action_begin_msg "Starting vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver ${OPTIONS2}"

;;

stop)
log_action_begin_msg "Stopping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY}"


log_action_begin_msg "Stopping vncserver for user '${USER}' on localhost:${DISP$
su ${USER} -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :${DISPLAY2}"

;;

restart)
$0 stop
$0 start
;;
esac
```

I was then able to use vncviewer on my windows pc to connect to display 1 and display two, hence somewhat mimicking a dual screen setup.  It works for me.  If anyone has any warnings or insight on why this shouldn't be done I would be happy to get the feedback.